# How do I search for a phrase in a piece of text in C#?

Tags: c#, string, linq, full-text-search

For example, I have list of texts which each text looks like something like this:

> We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed. Provide
>   details. Share your research.If your question is about this website

and I want to search for `can be answered` through the list of text and return the text above as a text which has `can be answered`. How should I do this?

I tried `Contains()` but it returns nothing. My code looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<App_ProjectTask> temp;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
{
    temp = dc.App_ProjectTasks.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(query) || x.Description.Contains(query));
    if (temp.Count() > 0)
    {
        results = temp.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code for your current test please.. Contains will answer yes/no if exact match is found.

Comment: I think you want the SubString function - http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring

Comment: switch to linux and use grep ;)  Sorry, but you know we were all thinking it :)

Comment: @BugFinder the code works fine if the query is only one word

Comment: Have you tried the code suggestions below - I added one, in  my code, I've done roughly what you did however it works for me with multiple words, however if you mean you want to search for 2 words but in any order.. then let me know, I can change my answer to cover that its easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me: Which is basically what you did, but I showed my class..

```
    private void WriteLine(String text)
    {
        textBox1.Text += text + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<TestClass> list = new List<TestClass>();

        list.Add(new TestClass { Title = "101 unanswered questions", Description = "There are many questions which go unanswered, here are our top 1001" });
        list.Add(new TestClass { Title = "Best of lifes questions", Description = "Many of lifes questions answered" });
        list.Add(new TestClass { Title = "Top 10 smart answers", Description = "Top 10 smart answers for common interview questions" });

        var results =
            list.Where(x => x.Description.Contains("answered questions") | x.Title.Contains("answered questions"));
        foreach (TestClass res in results)
        {
            WriteLine(String.Format("Title: {0}, Desc: {1}", res.Title, res.Description));
        }
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public String Title;
    public String Description;
    public String Contents;

    public TestClass()
    {
        Title = "";
        Description = "";
        Contents = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String text = "We prefer questions that can be answered, "+
               "not just discussed.Provide details. Share your research."+
               "If your question is about this website";
if (text.Contains("can be answered"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Text found");
}
```

The above code outputs `Text found`.

To get all the `String`s that have the text do something like this:

```
var query =
    from text in yourListOfTexts
    where text.Contains("can be answered")
    select text;
```

Comment: I would add a couple of ToLowers(), or create an extension for ContainsIgnoreCase()

Comment: @Ketchup You are assuming the OP wants to ignore the case.

Comment: @NominSim But this make sense to ignore the case... so it a good point to mention how to avoid the case.

Answer (score 3):

Contains should work.

```
var strList = new List<String>();
string itemSearch = "string to search for";

foreach (string str in strList)
{
    if(str.Contains(itemSearch))
    {
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would add a couple of ToLowers(), or create an extension for ContainsIgnoreCase()

Comment: Depends if hes looking for phrases that maybe in more than 1 line and wants all lines

Answer (score 0):

There's a few mentions of using ToLower() for the contains method
For performance you should use string.IndoexOf("string", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

That is if the OP needs his search to be case insensitive

[Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
 IEnumerable<App_ProjectTask> temp;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
{
temp = dc.App_ProjectTasks.Where(x => x.Title.ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower()) || x.Description.ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower()));
if (temp.Count() > 0)
{
    results = temp.ToList();
}
}
```